# SQL Exception Handling (not in stored procedure)

Tags: sql, error-handling, mariadb

I have some MariaDb maintenance scripts that have the form:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_TASK(OUT RESULT BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Error running SAMPLE_TASK';
        SHOW ERRORS;
        SET RESULT=FALSE;
    END;

    -- DO SOMETHING HERE    

    SET RESULT=TRUE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE RUN_TASKS()
BEGIN
    DECLARE SUCCESS BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;

    IF (SUCCESS) THEN
        CALL SAMPLE_TASK(SUCCESS);
    END IF;
    IF (SUCCESS) THEN
        CALL SAMPLE_TASK2(SUCCESS);
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL RUN_TASKS();
```

The gist of it is that there are a series of tasks that are broken out into stored procedures.  We want to execute each in turn aborting if we encounter an error.

This has worked well for us until now due to the fact one of our tasks we want to add will modify  triggers, and it seems that creating a trigger within a stored procedure is not supported.

Since we can't add triggers in the stored procedures we are looking to do it outside of them, such as by adding a CREATE TRIGGER statement after the call to RUN_TASKS.  The problem we have with that is that we can't find a way to handle errors at that level.  From what I've been able to find declaring handlers can only be done at the procedure level, and MariaDb doesn't seem to offer try/catch like some some other DB products.

So the questions are: 1) Does anyone know how to create a trigger from within a stored procedure?  2) How do you add error handling outside of a stored procedure?  Thanks

Comment: Check [Using Compound Statements Outside of Stored Programs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-compound-statements-outside-of-stored-programs/).

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks for the reference.  I'm not sure how that helps address either of the questions.